# Retrieve value from database trigger with loopback

Tags: loopback

I use loopback with a postgrsql database. In my database I have a trigger function to automatically fill some columns.

Is it possible with loopback to retrieve the values create by the database trigger in a after save event?

Is there an equivalent to SQL "returning" in loopback?